# 2 DetailsView validation conflict problem

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 DetailsView.
The first one is hidden (display:none) with DefaultMode=Insert, has RequiredFieldValidator

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valRequireAddedBy" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="txtAddedBy" SetFocusOnError="true" 
     Text="Your name is required."  Display="Dynamic">
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The second one, in edit mode.
When I try to submit it I get an error:

> htmlfile: Can't move focus to the
>   control because it is invisible, not
>   enabled, or of a type that does not
>   accept the focus.

Only if i remove the validator from first DetailsView it works.

Comment: please post the code for your EditMode DetailsView, that might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the `ValidationGroup` property on the validators to create two groups, one for each `DetailsView`? I'm not sure how you're firing the event that causes validation in each case, so I don't know if you can associate a `ValidationGroup` with the firing control or not...

Comment: I don't have any validationsgroups on the page so will try to add them.

Comment: I get the error when i click on a button but before it reaches it's code (I put a breakpoint on first line of button click event) and get an error before the breakpoint is reached.

Comment: if you have the button in a template (e.g. it's not auto-generated), set its CausesValidation property to false

Comment: @rm, i have buttons. in what DetailsView i should set it? in second? in both?

Comment: @dani: whatever button you click resulting in error should have its CasesValidation set to false.

Answer (score -1):

In your second DetailsView, set CausesValidation property to false

That way your "EditMode" details view won't cause the validation to fire

I guess DetailsView does not expose CausesValidation property, you'd have to deal with it on your [DetailsView.UpdateItem event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.updateitem.aspx)

Comment: there is no CausesValidation property in DetailsView.